# Remote image as tab bar icon in TabBarIOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, uitabbar

I want to load a user's profile picture and use it as the tab bar icon for the profile tab in my React Native app. How can I accomplish this with the TabBarIOS component?

Answer (score 0):

You can point the `icon` prop of `<TabBarIOS.item>` to the image you'd like to use as the icon. For example,

```
<TabBarIOS>
  <TabBarIOS.item icon={pathToProfilePicture}>
    // component to render here
  </TabBarIOS.item>
</TabBarIOS>
```